# Convertir Video (<100 MB) a BASE64

Tags: java, android-studio, video

Buenas, estoy utilizando estas lineas de código para enviar vídeos en base64 a un servidor, pero de un tiempo para acá comenzaron fallar el envió de vídeos de más de 50 mb. He leido que divida el archivo y otras cosas, pero cuando hago eso el base 64 lo genera incompleto.

```
 InputStream is = activity.getContentResolver().openInputStream(uriFileVideo);

            ByteArrayOutputStream byteBuffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

            // this is storage overwritten on each iteration with bytes
            int bufferSize = 1024;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

            // we need to know how may bytes were read to write them to the byteBuffer
            int len = 0;
            while ((len = is.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                byteBuffer.write(buffer, 0, len);
            }
        String tempData = Base64.encodeToString(byteBuffer.toByteArray(), Base64.DEFAULT);
```

En **Base64.encodeToString** se presentra el error de java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 156050688 byte allocation with 16777216 free bytes and 121MB until OOM

Comment: Javier, porque no envias el archivo tal y como es en bytes? Seria mucho mas rapido. Convert 50MB a base64 duraria una eternidad.

Comment: lo que sucede es que el servidor a donde se quiere guardar solo acepta base64 y no lo quieren cambiar a bytes.

Comment: cuando dices `He leido que divida el archivo y otras cosas, pero cuando hago eso el base 64 lo genera incompleto.` deberias de poner ese codigo ya que es la idea principal es "dividir" el archivo y con eso funcionaria.